# Azure Stream Analytics - no output events

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics, cortana-intelligence

I have a problem with azure stream analytics job. Job monitor shows incoming input events (from Event Hub) but there are no output events or errors. Job is really simple, just to write every input to azure blob storage:

SELECT * FROM input

Any suggestions what could be wrong?

Update!
It was a bug in Azure Stream Analytics and it's already solved by Microsoft.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to include INTO clause?

```
SELECT
    *
INTO
    [output]
FROM
    [input]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have verified that events are coming into the system, it's likely that the job is encountering an error during processing or writing to output.  Make sure that your input fields are in the set of [supported data types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn835065.aspx) and use a CAST statement if they aren't.  To hone in on the root cause, you may also want to pick a field or two to project instead of using a SELECT *.

You mentioned that there aren't any errors but make sure to check the following sources of troubleshooting/diagnostic information:

- Top-level status of your job (Processing, Degraded, etc.).  Definition for each status is here: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/stream-analytics-developer-guide/
- Use the "Test Connection" button on your inputs and outputs to verify connectivity
- Check the "Diagnosis" value for your inputs and outputs and click the name of the input/output for more detail, if applicable
- Look in the Operations Logs for any Warnings or Errors

Comment: This seems like more of a comment on the question, rather than an answer.  Please post it as such when you can.