# Unable to get output in Azure Stream Analytics

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics

I am trying to complete Azure Stream analytics job as per the article [microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/transform-data-with-azure-stream-analytics/). It is about Transforming data by using Azure Stream Analytics. I have completed each and every step carefully and crosschecked it. Take the same input file and ran the same query as mentioned in the article, but I am unable to get any output. The job is running for more than 2 hour for a single line output.

Diagnosis: I diagnose through the "Diagnose and Solve Problem" in stream analytics job and came on the conclusion that it is not able to get the input as the Input Event are shown 0 all the time.

P.S. I ran the test over the query on the sample data and it gave the desired output.

JSON: it is a simple json

```
{
    "City" : "Reykjavik",
    "Coordinates" :
    {
        "Latitude": 64,
        "Longitude": 21
    },
    "Census" :
    {
        "Population" : 125000,
        "Municipality" : "Reykjavík",
        "Region" : "Höfuðborgarsvæðið"
    }
}
```

Query:

```
SELECT City,
Coordinates.Latitude,
Coordinates.Longitude
INTO streamoutput
FROM streaminput
```

P.S.: it is not a duplicate of the [Azure Stream Analytics - no output events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29562879/azure-stream-analytics-no-output-events)

Comment: Hi, one issue may be the date of the file and the storage container. When you start the ASA job with "NOW" it will scan the data from the current time (in UTC). However due to time difference, that mean your blob storage date path may have the date in the past. Can you start the ASA job from a previous date (e.g. from the day before) instead of "NOW" to make sure it will scan this file? ASA is meant for real time, so is meant to focus for new data (on IoT Hub, Event Hubs or blob storage).

Comment: @Jean-Sébastien Thank you for the reply, I'll try to test this.

Comment: @Amit, Were you able to get this to work?